# How to choose one from two classes located in different modules

Tags: python, argparse

I have two similar classes "class1" and "class2" in module "classes" in my PyCharm project. 
I wish to import one of them to different module with every start up of program with use of `argparse` but I don't how to do it and I can't find any example. Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you just `import classes` and then use `classes.class1` or `classes.class2` depending on whatever condition your require?

Comment: what about condition?

Comment: The only condition is my will to start once with this class and once with the other. So the best option is to make it from command line like: program.py -class1 or -class2. So my question is how to do it with argparse.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to use your argparse arguments as a switch:

```
import sys
import argparse

def get_args():
    parser = parser.ArgumentParser(description='My Args')
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--myclass", dest="myclass", choices=['class1', 'class2'], help="pick a class")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def main():
    args = get_args()
    if args.myclass == 'class1':
        from classes import class1 as c1
    elif args.myclass == 'class2':
        from classes import class2 as c2
    else:
        sys.exit("Please pick a class to import")
    # do stuff
```

To run and select class1:

```
python3 myfunc.py -c class1
```

would import class1